# WebGL "project" function

Tags: webgl

Hi can anyone help me please with the following.

I need to do a world to screen conversion on a WebGL scene.

Keeping is real simple, I am rendering a line from the origin (0,0,0) to the point (1,0,0) and I want find the screen (x,y) position of the end of the line (1,0,0) and put a canvas element there displaying the letter x.

How to transform that point to screen coordinates?

I've almost done it but there's some kind of scaling problem.

I'm using glMatrix and in my rendering code I have:

```
mat4.perspective(45, this.m_WebGLContext.viewportWidth / this.m_WebGLContext.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0, this.m_projectionMatrix);
this.m_modelViewMatrix = mat4.lookAt(this.m_eye, this.m_centre, this.m_up);
```

So I have a view matrix and a projection matrix. My conversion function is as follows:

```
FieldViewer.prototype.Project = function(xzyArray, viewMatrix, projectionMatrix, nViewportWidth, nViewportHeight)
{
    var viewProjectionMatrix = mat4.create();
    mat4.multiply(projectionMatrix, viewMatrix, viewProjectionMatrix);

    var point3D = [0,0,0];
    mat4.multiplyVec3(viewProjectionMatrix, xzyArray, point3D);

    var nWinX = Math.round(((point3D[0] + 1) / 2.0) * nViewportWidth);
    var nWinY = Math.round(((1 - point3D[1]) / 2.0) * nViewportHeight);

    return [nWinX, nWinY];
}
```

It works BUT no quite. If I call it with the point [1,0,0] the screen x,y returned does not coincide with the end of the drawn line, but is does always lie on the line (either before of after it's end).

A clue here must be in the fact that when I alter the eye position to rotate the scene the calculated screen point is (as I say) on the line (but not coincident with it the end at 1,0.0) BUT when I zoom the camera away or towards the origin with the mouse wheel the scene correctly zooms in an out but the above function just returns the same values all of the time. My zoom function just modifies m_eye to move it toward or away from the origin. I see the line getting bigger and smaller but the 'x' doesn't move at all. Yet it moves correctly if I rotate the eye position about the origin.